# freelance writer with just a computer

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction

I am working on a project where I am getting checks to the sum 250,000.00 for writing article in a magazine. I just have one expense and that is internet to do research for this project, The computer I am using is old. I am looking to see how I can keep most of the money and not pay around 50% to taxes. Any ideas would be great .

Comment: Be very, very careful that you are not being scammed. $250,000 is not a credible payment for writing a magazine article unless maybe it's being optioned for a movie or a TV series. That sort of payment would be more typical as an advance on a novel from a best-selling author.

Comment: Unfortunately freelance writing is one of those jobs that attracts a lot of con artists out to take advantage of desperate people: [Beware Of Freelance Writer Scams](https://writingcooperative.com/beware-of-freelance-writer-scams-8d4ba14711af). Big newsstand outlets like Vogue and Wired typically pay freelancers between $1.50 and $3.00 per word. Unless you are Michael Lewis, already getting movie offers for his yet to be written article on FTX, nobody is going to be paying your $250,000 for a series of magazine articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deduct you business expenses - the computer you're using (prorated if you use it for this business only partially), the internet (again, prorated if not used exclusively for business), business use of your home (the part *exclusively* used for business), your business office expenses, business travel, anything else that you pay as part of your work as a writer (has to be *ordinary* and *necessary* for the job). Make sure to keep all the receipts and track mileage for travel.

What's left is your schedule C income.

Comment: Can I deduct the time it took me to get this project ? It took about three months and a lot of writing samples.

Comment: @Jefferson time is not an expense. You can only deduct money you actually spent.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do for the sample work I did to get this job ?

Comment: @Jefferson if you didn't spend any money - then there's nothing to deduct. Time is your asset, not an expense. Time is what you're being compensated for, this is part of what you sell.

Answer (score 4):

1. Looks very very much like a scam to me. Be very careful about spending the money. Under no circumstances whatsoever send any money back. If you are asked to send money back then it’s not 90% a scam, but 100%.
2. Be happy that you have no expenses. Once you are 100% sure there is no scam, you can buy a nice desk, office chair, top of the range laptop, large monitor, and deduct it from taxes. In the uk you’d start a limited company, pay money into your pension (tax free), and leave money in the company as savings (19% corporation tax until you take the money out).
3. If your articles are printed for real in a widely distributed magazine that you can buy on any newsstand, that’s a sign it might not be a scam.